# Resize Boot Partition Next to An Extended Partition

Tags: linux-mint, partition, home, gparted, livecd

I'm a new user of Linux and I installed Linux Mint 18.2.
I created 2 partitions:

- Boot / Root (Namely `/`).
- Home (`/home`).

I underestimated the size needed for the Boot / Root and only set it 25GB.
I now need to resize it.
I used LiveCD to run GParted and this is what I have:

[image]

Can anyone guide me how can I resize the partitions without loosing any data?
It seems I must delete the `sdf2` partition completely which means data is lost.

Is there any other way to do it (I don't have anything besides the disks above)?
On worse case scenario I don't mind losing all data on `/home` but I want the system to work as before.

Please guide me and remember those are my first steps in the Linux World.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you considered moving your rootfs comtents to the larger partition? I'm assuming the larger partition has /home, but that can be accommodated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GParted:

First "Move/Resize" `/dev/sda5`to the right. To do that, right click on the line reading "/dev/sdb5", select "Resize/Move"; then in the next window drag the handle on the left of the partition to the right (as far as you want to reclaim free space to the left), or modify the value for "Free space preceeding" . Select "Resize/Move" button and then "Apply all Operations", which will then take some time as the data have to be moved to the right.

When finished, do the same with the extended partition, i.e. select "extended partition", resize to the right as far as possible.

Last, select "/dev/sda1", select "Resize/Move" again, and extend to the right into the now unallocated space.

If you do not want to play around with partitions, you might use some space in `/home` to hold data from `/`using softlinks. Find some folder with lots of data (e.g. using `du -hs /*`), move it somewhere in `/home`, and create a softlink: `ln -s /home/<path_to_new_folder> /<name_of_moved_folder>`. You should **not** do this for system folders like `/bin`, `/usr` or `/var`, but maybe for subfolders (e.g. `/var/log`).

Comment: Indeed. What I missed was the step not only `sdb5` (What would be the term for that?) but also the extended partition.